# CSS File isn't linking properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm starting to dig into web development again and I thought I would just cover the absolute basics to start with. For whatever reason my stylesheet isn't linking and I've done, what I believe, is how you properly approach this. If I have all of the files inside of just the main project directory it links properly and works, but I have a structure like this: Project/resources/css(css files), html(html files), javascript(js files) and a link like this to the css file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/styles.css">
```

But this won't work at all for some reason.
If I structure the project like this: Project/index.html, styles.css, script.js , it will work when I link it like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

I thought I was linking it properly so it's not making much sense to me. Any help would be appreciated!
Note: I have looked through other Stack overflow posts where people had the same issue which is why I thought the way I linked the file was correct

Structure in VS Code:
[image]

Comment: you have to add a dot before pathing <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/styles.css"> and two dots if you want to jump out current folder <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/styles.css">

Comment: is html file is in project folder

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. It is in the project folder

Comment: I have also added a photo showing the structure in VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full URL: http://yourwebsite.com/resources/css/styles.css
Otherwise, check if you are in root folder (in browser)
eg. localhost/folder/index.html
in this case, the initial '/' in your link will point to folder/resources, not resources as root

Comment: Ahh I see what I've been doing wrong now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

So in order to go to a parent directory, You would do the `../css/styles.css`
Hope that helps.